# Please tell me the unicode character of the square symbol

Tags: xml

Please tell me what is the unicode character of the marked area in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [control code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), there are lots of different values that could produce that.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be an invalid symbol which is displayed as a square -- there is too little information here to actually tell you what it is is.   Your best option is to take the text and paste it into `od -c` (assuming you have access to a unix machine), and see what od tells you.